# Homotopy excision-type theorem for mapping cones of inclusions

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I'm working through Tammo tom Dieck's "Algebraic Topology" and am slightly stumped by an exercise in section 7.2.

Exercise 7.2.3:

> Let $X = A \cup B$ and suppose that $X$ is still covered by the interiors of $A$ and $B$. Show that the inclusion $C(B, A \cap B) \hookrightarrow C(X, A)$ is a weak homotopy equivalence.

In the notation of this book, when $Y$ is a subspace of $X$, $C(X, Y)$ is the mapping cone of the inclusion: $C(X, Y) = X \cup Y \times I / (Y \times \{1\})$. Also note that a blanket assumption in this section is that spaces are compactly generated.

The statement of the theorem makes it look tantalizing close to a homotopy excision theorem. We would have to relate $\pi_n(C(X, A))$ to $\pi_n(X, A)$ and likewise for $(B, A \cap B)$ but this seems plausible. However, even if we could do such a thing we have no assumptions about $\pi_i(A, A \cap B)$ which seems necessary for applying any sort of homotopy excision theorem.

Another approach that I'm hoping can be avoided is to directly write out the mapping cone for $C(B, A \cap B) \hookrightarrow C(X, A)$ (which can be written as a single big quotient since everything is compactly generated) and just show that this is contractible. However, this looks like it would be more than a little troublesome, so I'm hoping there's a more elegant approach.

Am I missing some much more direct approach to this problem? Or is there a missing assumption on the exercise?

Edit: I am now (even) more pessimistic about using the homotopy excision theorem. It seems that I can easily relate $\pi_n(X, A)$ and $\pi(F(X, A))$ where, $F(X,A)$ is the mapping space, *not* the mapping cylinder.

Comment: Go back to $\S$ 4.2, replace the inclusions by the double mapping cylinders, and work with these instead. See Proposition 4.2.3, for example, which assumes numerability but gives a genuine homotopy equivalence.

Comment: @Tyrone Thanks! That was was the insight I was missing :)

Comment: In case someone else stumbles upon this, I'll also add that Theorem 6.7.9 is the workhorse lemma needed to establish that the appropriate maps are weak equivalences.